# Django formset dynamic add row to table

Tags: django, dynamic, html-table, row, inline-formset

i have created a formset that is rendering in table and when i add a row the input box only is rendered in the first row and the second row is only the template code appearing.

the table will be a form posted to a view function for Formset process to capture all the data in the added dynamic table with add row.

HTML

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Dashboard - Brand</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/Navigation-Clean.css' %}">
</head>

<body id="page-top">
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm border rounded shadow-sm navigation-clean">
            <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a><button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1" class="navbar-toggler"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                    id="navcol-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">My Startup</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Campaigns</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Guide</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown nav-item"><a data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#">Account</a>
                            <div role="menu" class="dropdown-menu"><a role="presentation" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a><a role="presentation" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reset Password</a><a role="presentation" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Out</a></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 31px;">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-4" style="padding: 0;padding-top: 2;">
                        <form id="my-form" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="card-body" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);"><button id="Add" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">+ Add</button>
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                {% for form in formset %}
                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width: 21px;"></th>
                                            <th style="width: 295px;">Name</th>
                                            <th style="width: 257px;">Position</th>
                                            <th style="width: 59px;">Service</th>
                                            <th style="width: 267px;">Previouse Position</th>
                                            <th style="width: 64px;">Service</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>

                                            <td><button id="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">-</button></td>
                                            <td>{{form.name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{form.position}}</td>
                                            <td>{{form.service}}</td>
                                            <td>{{form.Previous_Position}}</td>
                                            <td>{{form.service_exp}}</td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <tr></tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="container-fluid"></div>
            </div>
            <footer class="bg-white sticky-footer">
                <div class="container my-auto">
                    <div class="text-center my-auto copyright"><span>Copyright © Brand 2019</span></div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div><a class="border rounded d-inline scroll-to-top" href="#page-top"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a></div>

        <script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/js/tt.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/js/theme.js' %}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

JS Code for adding rows:

````````
var html = '<tr><td><button id="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">-</button></td><td>{{form.name}}</td><td>{{form.position}}</td><td>{{form.service}}</td><td>{{form.Previous_Position}}</td><td>{{form.service_exp}}</td></tr>';

$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#Add', function(){
        $('tbody').append(html);
    })

});
```````
````````

Comment: any body can help and advise

Comment: i came to understand that JS dosnt work with django tags, so is there a better way to append the form with js and django tags

Comment: Happened to come here searching for something similar. Have you found your solution yet? Can I have a look at your **forms.py**?

Comment: i didnt really got through so i just used a CRUD operation with single template